# radio button parent in code

Tags: basic4android

In B4A, it is possible to add radio buttons to a parent (or group them) - such as a panel, instead of using designer? I have used addview to add 3 radio buttons to a panel but no luck.

I was using designer and then decided to try 100% code but I am having no luck getting them to select properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem adding radio buttons with code. Can you post the code that you tried?